# How to create an SVG with JFreeChart?

Tags: java, svg, jfreechart

On the JFreeChart web site it says that the library can output the chart in vector format.

From the JFreeChart site:

> - support for many output types, including Swing components, image files (including PNG and JPEG), and vector graphics file formats
>     (including PDF, EPS and **SVG**);

But how can I actually output in SVG format?

There is a way using the Apache Batik library, but from the statement above I would think JFreeChart can do it without Batik.

I could figure out the output for PNG and JPG in the ChartUtilities class, but there seems to be no class for vector graphics output.

Comment: There is a thread about this here: http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24365

Comment: @assylias That link is dead by now, do you recall what the conclusion of the thread was?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, [`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) supports SVG in the sense that it can be used in conjunction with [`Batik`](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) or [`JFreeSVG`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreesvg/), which are required. Related resources include these:

- [*The JFreeChart Developer Guide*](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/devguide.html)<sup>†</sup>, discussed [here](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/issues/253).
- [*Saving JFreeChart as SVG vector images using Batik*](http://dolf.trieschnigg.nl/jfreechart/).
- [`JFreeSVG`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreesvg), which can "generate content in SVG format using the standard `Java2D` drawing API, `Graphics2D`." Demonstration programs may be found [here](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos/tree/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/graphics2d/svg/demo), including this `SVGBarChartDemo1` excerpt:

  ```
    JFreeChart chart = createChart(createDataset());
    SVGGraphics2D g2 = new SVGGraphics2D(600, 400);
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 400);
    chart.draw(g2, r);
    File f = new File("SVGBarChartDemo1.svg");
    SVGUtils.writeToSVG(f, g2.getSVGElement());
  ```

<sup>†</sup><sub>*Disclaimer: Not affiliated with Object Refinery Limited; just a satisfied customer and very minor contributor.*</sub>

Comment: [JFreeSVG](http://www.jfree.org/jfreesvg/) is another option that is available now.

Answer (score 2):

To just make it simple for other readers, the following code converts a jFreeChart to a SVG by using jFreeSVG:

```
import org.jfree.graphics2d.svg.SVGGraphics2D;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public String getSvgXML(){
    final int widthOfSVG = 200;
    final int heightOfSVG = 200;
    final SVGGraphics2D svg2d = new SVGGraphics2D(widthOfSVG, heightOfSVG);

    final JFreeChart chart = createYourChart();
    chart.draw(svg2d,new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, widthOfSVG, heightOfSVG));

    final String svgElement = svg2d.getSVGElement();
    return svgElement;
}
```

To write the SVG elements to a PDF file, you can use the following code to generate a byte[] out of your SVG and then write it to a file. For this case I use [apache batic](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) :

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import org.apache.batik.transcoder.Transcoder;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput;
import org.apache.fop.svg.PDFTranscoder;

public byte[] getSVGInPDF(){ 
     final Transcoder transcoder = new PDFTranscoder();
     final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     final TranscoderInput transcoderInput = new TranscoderInput(
     new ByteArrayInputStream(getSvgXML().getBytes()));
     final TranscoderOutput transcoderOutput = new TranscoderOutput(outputStream);
     transcoder.transcode(transcoderInput, transcoderOutput);
     return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to trashgod 's answer

It seems that JFreeSVG is far more efficient than Batik : http://www.object-refinery.com/blog/blog-20140423.html